# Why is the Fourier transform valid only for absolutely integrable signals?

Tags: fourier-transform, integration

Why is the Fourier transform valid only for absolutely integrable signals?

For example, why can't we do the Fourier transform of exponential order functions?

Comment: The Fourier transform can be also defined for energy signals that are not integrable (for example, the sinc function). See Chapter 6 of "A Foundation in Digital Communication" by A. Lapidoth, available for free online.

Comment: So the Fourier Transform for $e^{at}$, for $a$ a real positive number, is ....?

Answer (score 2):

**Fourier on exponential functions can indeed make sense**. In theory, under specific conditions. And  in practical DSP, not likely.

There are so many conditions under which Fourier transformations exist that whole books are devoted to them, like   D. C. Champeney, [A Handbook of Fourier Theorems](https://www.worldcat.org/title/handbook-of-fourier-theorems/oclc/30862344),  Cambridge University Press, 1987. And the domain remains an open topic, in other words not all conditions are known, under which Fourier series are unique for instance.

Simply put: if $x(t)$ is absolutely integrable ($x\in L_1$ space), so is $x(t)e^{-jwt}$, by the virtue of the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), since $|x(t)e^{-jwt}|\le | x(t)|$. As such, this is a very direct condition to satisfy. 
By the way, 
note that $e^{-jwt}$ IS NOT absolutely integrable, an interesting paradox.

In signal processing applications and in statistics, as orthogonality or energy preservation is important, it is common to further restrict the domain to $x\in L_1 \cap L_2$. And this is not necessary for discrete signals, as  $\ell_2 \subset \ell_1$.

As exponential functions $\exp(-at)$, $a\neq 0$, are not integrable on the whole $\mathbb{R}$-line, they should be truncated or windowed to be used in practice.

And if you REALLY want to define it, you can go to some distribution theory, see for instance [Fourier transform of (real) exponential](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41959/fourier-transform-of-real-exponential), where you can restrict the space of tests functions in the spirit of windowing.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Fourier transform is defined as $X(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt$. For this to have closed form expression, $x(t)$ should be absolutely integrable. But this is just a sufficient condition but not a necessary condition. That is, even though signal is not absolutely integrable, still Fourier transform exist.

For exponential function,  the term $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{at} e^{-j\omega t} dt$ cannot have closed form expression.